# A Dialogue with a Custom Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialog

I would like to create a dialogue with a custom layout.  The Android API documents suggest that I always use Alert Dialogue, and that I do not try to instantiate the Dialogue class directly.

This is extremely difficult, because the builder for AlertDialog does not allow custom views.  I was lucky enough to find support for an adapter, but it is still extremely difficult to gain access to a layout inflater.

Is there a reason why a fragment class does not have getContext()?
How do you get a layoutInflater inside a fragment when the savedInstanceState is null?

If it is possible, what is the best way to create a fully custom dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the dialogue fragment does not support...

getLayoutInflater(Bundle) (because the SavedInstanceState is null), or
getContext()

you can use getActivity().getLayoutInflater().